# Load PHP value with jquery into textbox inside of jquery statement

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Im trying to load a numeric value from the database into the textbox named jTagLabel. Its from the JTag API, and the way it is set up, the html code is inside of a jquery.

So first I make a jquery statement to load the value of a span called span1 from a php file called tag count. Ive tested this part and it works fine.

```
$('#jTagLabel.val()').load('tagcount.php #span1');

$('<div style="width:'+options.defaultWidth+'px;height:'+options.defaultHeight+'px"class="jTagDrag">       <div class="jTagSave"><div class="jTagInput"><input type="text" value="" id="jTagLabel"></div><div class="jTagSaveClose"></div><div class="jTagSaveBtn"></div><div style="clear:both"></div></div>').appendTo(overlay);
```

What im trying to do is make the .load appear as the value=" " of "id=JTagLabel" above.
Any and all help is appreciated.

*Note, the Jquery .load statement is written after the div statement, but for this example, i placed it first.

Comment: `$('#jTagLabel.val()')` --- "Ive tested this part and it works fine." --- are you kidding?

Comment: What i meant was that I tested the load statement in plain text html ie (#div).load('tagcount.php #span1');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
$.get('tagcount.php', function(data) {
    var span_text = $('<div>')
                    .append(data)
                    .find('#span1').html();

    $('#jTagLabel').val(span_text);
});
```

That's how .load() does things. It does try to remove `<script>` tags though.

Comment: Hey, your posted method seems to grabbing the entire php file, how would i only grab the data from span1.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed the selector. I updated the answer to use it.